# Android FB Login fails on Samsung Galaxy 8/9 & many other devices

Tags: android, crash, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have an android app which crashes with the following error:

> The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call
>   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.

I'm initializing the sdk at the first available opportunity and it works fine on my test devices, one of which is a Samsung Galaxy J3.

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

I have many such crashes and I've found out around 500+ users have been impacted by this error. The crash rate is about 5%.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have internet permissions (androidManifest and runtime permissions)? Maybe your testing devices have Android 6 or previous and it crashes with higher versions because they need runtime permissions...

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: The app does have Internet Permissions. It is a functional app with over 30k installs on playstore. All of the crashes are happening on newer devices. I've tried to implement the latest Facebook SDK today. Just waiting to see how it functions. I've already rolled it out.